# updating cache problem

Tags: 14.04

I am new to ubuntu, and the system showed updates available, it shows some downloading but it does not send  a message confirming the updates were successful or something like that. after that I opened the system settigns and the updating icon. after going through the  tabs I click close amd a message appears that says the information about available software is out of date, I click to reload and it downloads a buch of files then it shows it is loading software list and it stops and goes away without showing anything else.
I open again the system settings and it does it all over again, never the update completes.
I can not update anything, not even firefox
any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you tried to perform the updates on the command line, eg with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?  What is the error message shown there, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The command `apt-get update` is to update list of available upgrades, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` are to upgrade your system.

Also you can do this by 3 steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: if you use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` is meaningless.